# Consul Installation on Windows

Tags: rabbitmq, consul, service-discovery

I want to install Consul for service discovery. I need installation and configuration process. How to proceed?

I want to use Consul for service discovery with rabbitmq.

Comment: So... you need this? https://www.consul.io/docs/install/index.html

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search turns up [this document](https://www.consul.io/intro/getting-started/install.html), which has all the information you need.